# Export products but only from one category

Tags: product, export, importexport

As far as I can see, I can export customers and products.
But when I only need products from one category I can't find that flag for it.

Is there a trick to to do that?

Comment: Are you willing to use an extension? If yes this might be helpful:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-products-import-and-export.html

Comment: I am willing to do, but it would be nice to understand the problem and maybe to enhanced it by myself.  I guess every extension has also its limitations and so if possible I would extend it by myself.  My only problem is that there is no well written documentation that I can use. :-(

Comment: Maybe something like shi will help you to access the products and get them http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/catalog_category#example_2._working_with_assigned_products

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to modify your products a bit, there is a trick.

If you change your sku naming convention to start with some code for your categories (like cat1-some-sku).  Then you can use the dataflow export filters for skus that start with cat1 to be exported only.  Of course this will only work if your products are not going to be in multiple categories.

[image]

Also this link can be helpful if you are interested to add a new attribute to filter on:  http://www.excellone.com/blog/magento-developer-notes/adding-new-export-filter-for-products-in-dataflow-profiles-in-magento-version-1-9-3/#.VOP7Thn0DqB